# Memory efficient algorithm for `take n (sort xs)` ("sorted prefix") problem

Tags: sorting, haskell, memory-management, lazy-evaluation

I want to take n biggest elements from lazy list.

I heard that mergesort implemented in Data.List.sort is lazy and it doesn't produce more elements than necessary. This might be true in terms of comparisons, but certainly isn't the case when it comes to memory usage. The following program illustrates the issue:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.Heap as Heap
import qualified Data.List as List

import System.Random.MWC
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vec

import System.Environment

limitSortL n xs = take n (List.sort xs)
limitSortH n xs = List.unfoldr Heap.uncons (List.foldl' (\ acc x -> Heap.take n (Heap.insert x acc) ) Heap.empty xs) 

main = do
  st <- create
  rxs :: [Int] <- Vec.toList `fmap` uniformVector st (10^7)

  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    ["LIST"] -> print (limitSortL 20 rxs)
    ["HEAP"] -> print (limitSortH 20 rxs)

  return ()
```

Runtime:

Data.List:

```
./lazyTest LIST +RTS -s 
[-9223371438221280004,-9223369283422017686,-9223368296903201811,-9223365203042113783,-9223364809100004863,-9223363058932210878,-9223362160334234021,-9223359019266180408,-9223358851531436915,-9223345045262962114,-9223343191568060219,-9223342956514809662,-9223341125508040302,-9223340661319591967,-9223337771462470186,-9223336010230770808,-9223331570472117335,-9223329558935830150,-9223329536207787831,-9223328937489459283]
   2,059,921,192 bytes allocated in the heap
   2,248,105,704 bytes copied during GC
     552,350,688 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
       3,390,456 bytes maximum slop
            1168 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0:  3772 collections,     0 parallel,  1.44s,  1.48s elapsed
  Generation 1:     5 collections,     0 parallel,  0.90s,  1.13s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time    0.82s  (  0.84s elapsed)
  GC    time    2.34s  (  2.61s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total time    3.16s  (  3.45s elapsed)

  %GC time      74.1%  (75.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,522,515,156 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  25.9% of total user, 23.7% of total elapsed
```

Data.Heap:

```
./lazyTest HEAP +RTS -s 
[-9223371438221280004,-9223369283422017686,-9223368296903201811,-9223365203042113783,-9223364809100004863,-9223363058932210878,-9223362160334234021,-9223359019266180408,-9223358851531436915,-9223345045262962114,-9223343191568060219,-9223342956514809662,-9223341125508040302,-9223340661319591967,-9223337771462470186,-9223336010230770808,-9223331570472117335,-9223329558935830150,-9223329536207787831,-9223328937489459283]
 177,559,536,928 bytes allocated in the heap
     237,093,320 bytes copied during GC
      80,031,376 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
         745,368 bytes maximum slop
              78 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0: 338539 collections,     0 parallel,  1.24s,  1.31s elapsed
  Generation 1:     2 collections,     0 parallel,  0.00s,  0.00s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time   35.24s  ( 35.46s elapsed)
  GC    time    1.24s  (  1.31s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total time   36.48s  ( 36.77s elapsed)

  %GC time       3.4%  (3.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    5,038,907,812 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  96.6% of total user, 95.8% of total elapsed
```

Clearly limitSortL is much faster, but it's also very memory hungry. On larger lists it hit's RAM size.

Is there a faster algorithm to solve this problem which isn't that memory hungry?

**Edit**: Clarification: I use Data.Heap from heaps package, I didn't try the heap package.

Comment: Can you give a reasonable upper bound on n?

Comment: What do you mean by n? Input list size or output list size?

Comment: The `n` that you introduced in the first line - i.e. the output list size.

Comment: This would be more compelling if you were working with real data. Generating an extremely large vector makes me suspicious; GHC plays tricks on you when it can decipher things about the data you create.

Comment: @Dan I think this is the right approach, since all it can tell is it will be some sort of random list of specific length. I've certainly seen this approach in other benchmarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've actually managed to solve the problem. The idea is to throw away fancy data structures and work by hand ;-)
Essentially we split input list into chunks, sort them, and foldl the `[[Int]]` list, selecting `n` smallest elements at each step.
The trickies part is merging accumulator with sorted chunk in proper way. We have to use `seq` or otherwise the lazyness will bite you and the result still need lot's of memory to compute. Additionally I mix merge with `take n`, just to optimize things more. Here is the whole program, along with previous attempts:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, PackageImports #-}     
module Main where

import qualified Data.List as List
import qualified Data.List.Split as Split
import qualified "heaps" Data.Heap as Heap -- qualified import from "heaps" package

import System.Random.MWC
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vec

import System.Environment

limitSortL n xs = take n (List.sort xs)
limitSortH n xs = List.unfoldr Heap.uncons (List.foldl' (\ acc x -> Heap.take n (Heap.insert x acc) ) Heap.empty xs)
takeSortMerge n inp = List.foldl' 
                        (\acc lst -> (merge n acc (List.sort lst))) 
                        [] (Split.splitEvery n inp)
    where
     merge 0 _ _ = []
     merge _ [] xs = xs
     merge _ ys [] = ys
     merge f (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y = let tail = merge (f-1) xs (y:ys) in tail `seq` (x:tail) 
                           | otherwise = let tail = merge (f-1) (x:xs) ys in tail `seq` (y:tail)


main = do
  st <- create

  let n1 = 10^7
      n2 = 20

  rxs :: [Int] <- Vec.toList `fmap` uniformVector st (n1)

  args <- getArgs

  case args of
    ["LIST"] ->  print (limitSortL n2 rxs)
    ["HEAP"] ->  print (limitSortH n2 rxs)
    ["MERGE"] -> print (takeSortMerge n2 rxs)
    _ -> putStrLn "Nothing..."

  return ()
```

Runtime performance, memory consumption, GC time:

```
LIST       3.96s   1168 MB    75 %
HEAP       35.29s    78 MB    3.6 %
MERGE      1.00s     78 MB    3.0 %
just rxs   0.21s     78 MB    0.0 %  -- just evaluating the random vector
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer, then. That will bring this answer to the top for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: It's only possible after two days. Unless someone posts better answer I'll do that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a whole lot of [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) specialized in doing exactly this. The partition based algorithm is the "classic one", but just like Quicksort it isn't really suitable for Haskell lists. The wikipedia doesn't show much related to functional programming, although I suspect that the "tournament selection" described is the same or not very different from your current mergesort solution.

If you are worried about memory consumption, you could use a priority Queue - it uses O(K) memory and O(N*logK) time overall:

```
queue := first k elements
for each element in the rest:
    add the element to the queue
    remove the largest element from the queue
convert the queue to a sorted list
```

Comment: Wikipedia says that selection algorithms are for taking the *nth* largest or smallest elements - not the *n*. That is, this is a problem of taking possibly multiple elements. In addition, the alternative mentioned in the question already *is* a type of queue.

Comment: However, yes, some of the material on that Wikipedia page does look potentially useful, e.g. the "Nonlinear general selection algorithm" section.

Comment: @Green: No. Taking the n-th largest means also finding all the other n-th largest elements in the process. Take a look at the partition one, it is just quicksort with one recursive call instead of two.

Comment: This is essentially what the OP is doing in his heap-based solution. I guess the real question is if there is a more efficient implementation.

Answer (score 2):

"Quicksort and k-th smallest elements," by the always engaging Heinrich Apfelmus:
http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/quicksearch.html

Comment: He lists 'smallest k = take k . sort' as his solution, which is exactly the LIST solution from my question.

Comment: @Tener: Read the whole thing. He goes on to discuss a number of better versions of sort for this purpose than that provided in Data.List.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me if I can't decipher

```
 Vec.toList `fmap` uniformVector st (10^7)
```

but how long will this list be? Is it clear that no matter how lazy mergesort is, it will at least have to realize the whole list?

Update:

> I heard that mergesort implemented in
>   Data.List.sort is lazy and it doesn't
>   produce more elements than necessary.

That tells nothing about mergesorts space consumption before it can start to deliver the first elements of a list. In any case, it'll have to walk (and thereby realize) the whole list, allocate to be merged sublists, etc.
Here is acitation from http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/merge/mergen.htm

> A drawback of mergesort is that it
>   needs an additional space of Θ(n) for
>   the temporary array b.
>
> There are different possibilities to
>   implement function merge. The most
>   efficient of these is variant b. It
>   requires only half as much additional
>   space, it is faster than the other
>   variants, and it is stable.

Comment: Well, no. It will have to realize the vector, not the list. And the vector is much more compact in this case.

Comment: Well, yes, you pass the list to sort. How could it find the n largest/smallest elements without even going once throgh the whole list?

Comment: I've never said that it can't traverse the whole list.

Comment: Is something wrong with my questions, or is there another reason why you don't give me a clue so I can estimate the size of the list (and the sublists that sort will invariably produce)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly saw your questions as being rhetorical. Please ask your questions more directly. I'm not saying that the behavior sort exhibits now is wrong. I ask for better algorithm to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Why then, can't we just establish how bad the current solution is? Maybe it turns out that it is not that bad. But until now, we only have your *claim* that this would be so.

Comment: The best possible solution will compute the result in Θ(output size) memory. This is actually trivial to do, see Data.Heap solution. The question is how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You might be misdiagnosing the problem. It might be a case of *too much* laziness, rather than too little.

Maybe you should try a stricter data structure, or a mutable array in the ST monad.

For the mutable array approach, you could limit the number of moves per insertion to `n/2` instead of `n-1`, by recording an index `h` that "points to" the head of the queue stored in the array, and allowing the queue to "wrap around" inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Memory efficiency is rarely haskell's strength.  That said, it is not that hard to produce a sorting algorithm that is more fully lazy than a mergesort.  For example, here is a simple quicksort:

```
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = qcombine (qsort a) b (qsort c) where
    (a,b,c) = qpart x (x:xs) ([],[],[])
qpart _ [] ac = ac
qpart n (x:xs) (a,b,c)
    | x > n = qpart n xs (a,b,x:c)
    | x < n = qpart n xs (x:a,b,c)
    | otherwise = qpart n xs (a,x:b,c)
qcombine (a:as) b c = a:qcombine as b c
qcombine [] (b:bs) c = b:qcombine [] bs c
qcombine [] [] c = c
```

I used explicit recursion to make it obvious what is going on.   Each part here is truly lazy, meaning that `qcombine` will never call `qsort c` unless it needs it.  This should keep your memory usage down if you just want the first few items.

You can build a better sorting algorithm for this specific task that uses quicksort style partions to get the first n items of the list in unsorted order.  Then just call a highly efficient sorting algorithm on those if you need them in order.

an example of that approach:

```
qselect 0 _ = []
qselect n [] = error ("cant produce " ++ show n ++ " from empty list")
qselect n (x:xs)
    | al > n = qselect n a
    | al + bl > n = a ++ take (al - n) b
    | otherwise = a ++ b ++ (qselect (n - al - bl) c) where
        (a,al,b,bl,c,cl) = qpartl x (x:xs) ([],0,[],0,[],0)

qpartl _ [] ac = ac
qpartl n (x:xs) (a,al,b,bl,c,cl)
    | x > n = qpartl n xs (a,al,b,bl,x:c,cl+1)
    | x < n = qpartl n xs (x:a,al+1,b,bl,c,cl+1)
    | otherwise = qpartl n xs (a,al,x:b,bl+1,c,cl)
```

Again, this code is not the cleanest, but I want to make it clear what it is doing.

For the case where you want to take a very low number, a selection sort is optimal.  For example, if you just want the highest element in the list, you can iterate through it once giving big theta of the size of the list.

On the other hand, if you want almost all the list, but dont care about getting it in order, you could repeatedly "delete" the lowest elements in the list.

Both of these approaches, and the quicksort above, are O(n^2), but what you want is to have a strategy that works in big O(k*n) often, and tends to not use a ton of space.

Another option is to use an in-place sorting algorithm to control memory usage.  I dont know of any lazy in-place sorts, but if they exist that would be perfect.